# Why was my question migrated to medical science?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions, specific-question, migration

Why was my [question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/22940/seboorrheic-dermatitis-fungi-environmental-factors) migrated to medical science?

My question was more about the condition( even if it is a condition in attention of the medical science) in itself( hypothesized causation by fungi) and the biological process than medical practise in the from of advice for prevention.

Comment: I migrated it because it is my experience that medical related questions are more likely to get an answer than here at biology.

Comment: @Chris Is the question off-topic here?

Comment: @canadianer Not necessarily, but I think the chances of getting a good answer are better over there.

Comment: @Chris, technically that's not a reason to migrate. But I do agree with migrating it, as it is a typical clinical question.

Comment: @AliceD The scope of the question had nothing to do with the medical teachings, medical practice, diagnosis or treatment. It was a question with a purely biological/pathological/physiological scope i.e understanding the condition in itself its reasons, causes and mechanism. Prevention and hygiene are secondary I first need to understand and only then do.